# Do git range operators always work the same way?

Tags: git

I just recently noticed that when you do
    git cherry-pick foo..bar

foo is not included. If your history looks like this:

```
bar
blubb
foo
```

the previous commit will only pick blubb and bar.
That's the same with

```
git log foo..bar
```

One can easily fix that by using

```
git log foo~..bar
```

I just couldn't find that documented and wanted to know if all commands that accept range operators in git work this way or if it depends on the specific command.

I guess the former but who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all Git commands that accept a revision will work with `~` that, in this form, specifies immediate parent of the revision. You can find a more detailed descriptions of Git revisions format [here](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitrevisions.html).